# Only allow members of a closed Facebook group to sign up to a website

Tags: ios, facebook, .htaccess, facebook-graph-api

I have an invite-only closed Facebook group with 17,000 members. I am working on an iOS app to cater to these 17,000 members, but them only.

How can I make sure that only group members create an account? Facebook's new Graph API doesn't seem to allow querying whether someone belongs to a certain group upon signing-up, and prevent signup if they don't...

Using htaccess, could I setup a signup page on my website that could only be accessed with the referrer `"facebook.com/groups/[groupid]"` and also disallow direct access (by manually typing the URL)?

Answer (score 0):

You should :

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/group

- Ask the user to first approve your Facebook App
- Ask for the user_groups permission
- Make a call to "me/groups"
- Verify if your user group is in the user's group
- If yes, allow further access.

Or doesn't this fit in your workflow or use case ?